# Refactoring iOS code: Decreasing the number of lines of code

Tags: ios, optimization, coding-style, refactoring

First time I'm posting a question here with a code that actually works!  However, I believe there is a way to decease the number of lines in code.  I'm hoping a guru can show me the way.

Here is the Storyboard Window for reference:

[image]

I have a Main ViewController with a containerView.  The ContainerView has it's own Navigation Controller.  Each Button (B1-B5) on the left of Main View Controller Segue's to it's respective Scene number. i.e. B2 will Push Scene 2 on to the stack.  B4 will Push Scene 4 on to the stack.  If visibleViewContoller is Scene 5, and the user presses B1, it will pop all the viewController until we reach Scene 1. So on and so forth.

Again the code below works fine, I'm just looking to shrink the size of the code for B1 and B2:

```
- (IBAction)B1Pressed:(id)sender {

UINavigationController *navController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray *VCs = [navController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
UIViewController *visibleViewController = [navController visibleViewController];

if (visibleViewController == [VCs objectAtIndex:0])
{
    return;
}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:1])
{
     [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:2])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:3])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:4])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:5])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
}

- (IBAction)B2Pressed:(id)sender {

UINavigationController *navController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray *VCs = [navController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
UIViewController *visibleViewController = [navController visibleViewController];

if (visibleViewController == [VCs objectAtIndex:0])
{
    STLMEatDrinkViewController *stlmEDVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B2"];
    [navController pushViewController:stlmEDVC animated:YES];
}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:1])
{
    return;
}

else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:2])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:3])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:4])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
else if (visibleViewController ==[VCs objectAtIndex:5])
{
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
 }
}
```

Now imagine writing this same code three more times for B3Pressed, B4Pressed, and B5Pressed.  I think it's way too much code and I'm almost positive there is a better approach to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You shall not compare objects using `==`. Use `isEqual:`.

2.) Loops.

```
int idx = [VCs indexOfObject:visibleViewController];

if (idx == 0) {
    STLMEatDrinkViewController *stlmEDVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B2"];
    [navController pushViewController:stlmEDVC animated:YES];
} else if (idx == 1) {
    return;
} else {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < idx; i++) {
        [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }

    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Comparing objects using == is fine in this case, we're expecting literally the same object aren't we?

Comment: @jrturton Technically it works, but it's generally considered bad style (I can't think of any occasion where `==` would not work, though).

Comment: @H2CO3.  That was fast and beautiful!  Your code works like a charm!  Thank you.

Comment: @ToMfromTO Your code causes an exception:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' I believe that's because I need to navigate through the UINavigationController by popping and pushing. Accessing them directly doesn't work because the view's have not been initialized (I'm thinking), I could be wrong. But thank you for trying. –

Comment: @user1107173 Your deduction is actually **downright wrong.** Read the error message. It's just that ToMfromTO tried to lazily over-simplify the task. He doesn't have any `if`s in his code - they're needed. You can't really simplify this code beyond what I did.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did try it with the if statement and got that error.  I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user1107173 It certainly is. But to find out what is wrong, you'll need to google the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers your problem:

```
- (IBAction)B1Pressed:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    UIViewController *B1ViewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [navController popToViewController:B1ViewController animated:YES];
}
```